# Why do I get NameError?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to clean up a string of all nonword chars, make it downcase, and compare `string.reverse` and `string` itself.

```
def palindrome?
  if self.reverse.gsub(/\W/, "").downcase == self
    return true
  end
end
```

Why do I get the following error? What should I do with `downcase` method?

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `downcase' for main:Object

Answer (score 0):

`downcase` is defined on `String`s.  Try:

```
 class String
   def palindrome?
     if self.reverse.gsub(/\W/, "").downcase == self
       true
     else
       false
     end
    end
  end

"radar".palindrome?  # => true
"hi".palindrome?  # => false
```

However, beware that monkey-patching well-known classes like `String` could totally bite you down the line.  Instead of the above, you could make a subclass of `String` that provides the `palindrome?` method.